# how to query same column with different criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, join, self-join

I have 2 tables sugar_distribution and farmer_dir.

sugar_distribution table has columns season_cd, farmer_id and Tons_supplied.
farmer_dir contains farmer_name and farmer_id. what I need is

```
Farmer_id       Farmer_name    Tons@2006         Tons@2012

123              Ramesh G       145.215           548.125
321              Ravish         214.123           783.215
```

season_cd is the year field. I want to analyse parties those supplied both in the years 2006 and  2012.  I tried below query but not getting what i want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT farmer_id,

(SELECT sum(tons)
 FROM sugar_distribution
 WHERE      (farmer_id = A.farmer_id) 
    AND (season_cd = 2)) AS T2006,

(SELECT sum(tons)
 FROM sugar_distribution
 WHERE      (farmer_id = A.farmer_id) 
    AND (season_cd = 8)) AS T2012

FROM sugar_distribution A 
WHERE A.season_cd = 2 OR A.season_cd = 8 order by to_number(farmer_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        SELECT farmer_id, MAX(t2006), MAX(t2012)
        FROM
        (
        SELECT farmer_id, sum(case when season_cd = 2 then tons else 0 end) t2006, SUM(case when season_cd = 8 then tons else 0 end) t2012
         FROM sugar_distribution
         WHERE      (farmer_id = A.farmer_id) 
            AND season_cd in (2,8)
           group by farmer_id, season_cd
         ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close.

```
select a.farmer_id, a.farmer_name,
 (select sum(tons_supplied)
            from sugar_distribution b
            where b.farmer_id = a.farmer_id
            and b.season_cd = 2) as t2006,
 (select sum(tons_supplied)
            from sugar_distribution b
            where b.farmer_id = a.farmer_id
            and b.season_cd = 8) as t2012
from farmer_dir a;
```

Sample fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9fe1/6)

Comment: This is working but not filtering data of 2006 and 2012 only. it is retrieving all data in the table farmer_dir. but I need only data that matches 2006 and 2012 criteria                                                 select a.farmer_id, a.farmer_name,
 (select sum(tons_supplied)
            from sugar_distribution b
            where b.farmer_id = a.farmer_id
            and b.season_cd = 2) as t2006,
 (select sum(tons_supplied)
            from sugar_distribution b
            where b.farmer_id = a.farmer_id
            and b.season_cd = 8) as t2012
from farmer_dir a;

Answer (score 0):

This is an aggregation query using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT fd.farmer_id, fd.farmer_name,
       sum(case when season_cd = 2 then tons else 0 end) as tons2006,
       sum(case when season_cd = 8 then tons else 0 end) as tons2012
from farmer_dir fd join
     sugar_distribution sd
     on fd.farmer_id = sd.farmer_id
group by fd.farmer_id, fd.farmer_name
having tons2006 > 0 and tons2012 > 0
```

The final `having` clause just ensures that the farmers have records for both years.

Comment: thats just a copy of my answer ;-). At least sort of